# firefox Card Verification at the last step of checkout

Tags: magento, error-handling, checkout, cart

just an update, the checkout works in IE but i get the problem in firefox Card Verification at the last step of checkout

Comment: It's basically impossible to tell what you are asking for, or about. Please edit your question to include as many relevant details as you can find, or we'll have no chance at helping with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using the stored credit card payment method unless you have PCI compliance. Invest your time in getting PayPal to work if you want to be able to take money online with minimal hassle.

If you are getting the CVV card logo images popup and ruining your cart, set the containing div to display:none in the CSS.